# Why is the interface method unresolvable?

Tags: java, android

I have code that calls on a interface I called "ListDescribable" for use with a custom ArrayAdapter.

The Interface is declared as follows:

```
public interface ListDescribable {
    String getCalledName();
    String getDescriptor();
    boolean isActive();
    void toggle();

}
```

I call on the interface methods here:

```
 listEntry = new DescribableEntry();
 listEntry.broadcastSwitch =(Switch) row.findViewById(R.id.list_entry_switch);
```

...

```
ListDescribable entry = data[position];
listEntry.broadcastSwitch.setChecked(entry.isActive());
```

I try to call isActive(), but the ide tells me that isActive cannot be resolved. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

edit:

DescribableEntry code:

```
static class DescribableEntry {
    Switch broadcastSwitch;
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemDescriptor;
    ImageView blueStatus;
}
```

Edit:
DescribableEntry is not the ListDescribable.  Under no circumstance does the ListDescribable methods getcalled on a DescribableEntry object.

as per request, data[] is an array of ListDescribable objects, declared in object initalization as a field variable. The class being used in the project is  for an interrupter, which is currently a placeholder:

```
public boolean isActive() { return false; }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your **isActive( )** method implementation and what type of object is **data[position]** returning

Comment: I can't see any reason why you should get that error message. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using android studio. I am as confused as heck right now, since I haven't seen any mistakes

Comment: Android studio is buggy. Have you tried rebuilding project or ignoring error message and trying to run it anyway?

Comment: tried to. a-studio tossed the whole thing back at me. Cleaning/rebuilding still left me with the same errors. I might have to go back to eclipse and configure it for android (which will be half a pain)

Comment: Or perhaps you have another class called `ListDescribable`?

Comment: Don't go back to eclipse. Android studio is much better.

Comment: mmm... probably, but I might have to if this thing doesn't work with me on this issue :P

Comment: Can you try adding public before your interface methods?

Comment: @Iamsomeone interface methods are implicitly `public`.

Comment: public is redundant in the face of interfaces. (sorry, couldn't resist the pun) All interface methods are inherently public. EDIT: ninja'd by above

Comment: Yeah sorry you're right

Comment: Then plase show us the class(es) implementing ListDescribable. Are they in the same package as the class calling the isActive method?

Comment: I reply with what I have said below. Also, no, but again, I repeat what I have said below in reply.

Comment: Have you tried putting the cursor in `ListDescribable` (next to `entry`) them doing ALT + left mouse click? It should take you to the interface  declaration. Maybe there's a rogue class called `ListDescribable` you forgot to delete?

Comment: Sorry CTRL + left mouse click

Comment: tried that the first time I saw the error, but no. There is no other usage of this term.

Comment: Ok, well I'm really sorry but I'm completely stuck in that case. Makes no sense.

Comment: Fixed. Result of my non-comprehension of type arguments. I set the object parameter of ArrayAdapter as ListDescribable, which shadowed? the interface name. While there were no other declarations of ListDescribable, the studio assumed that ListDescribable was a new class or something else. Thanks for all the help, though.

Comment: Damn! I should have got that! The clues were all there - you were even talking about an `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: lol, Well, it's my fault for not putting the entire SwitchArrayAdapter into the question. Would have been so much faster if I had done so.

Answer (score 1):

Your "data" table should implements "ListDescribable"

If "data[position]" is of type "DescribableEntry", so "DescribableEntry" should implements ListDescribable", and his methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your class implements the interface, otherwise the two will be completely separated.

```
static class DescribableEntry implements ListDescribable
{
... implement all interface methods here ...
}
```

You can read more about interfaces here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify, I apologize if it was not clear before.

Comment: @AlterionX you can't instantiate an interface direcly. Did you create some class(es) implementing ListDescribable?

Comment: yes, I did. But you should be able to call the interface methods knowing that the given object is, indeed, implementing the interface

Comment: @AlterionX You should provide us with the class implementing ListDescribable if possible

Comment: but the point of interfaces is that you can call the methods on a generic object for which the only thing the program knows is that it implements the interface. If there is an error with my other object (which there isn't) it should not affect the resolution of the interface methods.